# How can I array a vector in this matrix?

Tags: python

I'm making an exercise with associated matrix, and I have an error with the distancia.array function, but I don't now why I'm having this error.

```
import numpy as np
ciudades = []
arch = open("distancia.txt","r")
linea = arch.readline().strip()
matriz = np.zeros([10,10])

while  linea != "" :

    partes = linea.split(",")
    nombre = partes [0]
    nombre2 = partes[1]
    distancia = int(partes[2])

    if nombre not in ciudades :
        ciudades.append(nombre)
    if nombre2 not in ciudades :
        ciudades.append(nombre2)

    x = ciudades.index(nombre)
    y = ciudades.index(nombre2)

    distancia.array = matriz[x][y]
    distancia.array = matriz[y][x]
```

Comment: What, exactly, is the error you are getting? Can you provide the "distancia.txt" file?

Comment: `distancia.array` is not a function nor a package, right? Only a data member of some class instance. You're missing some import statements or definitions of `distancia`, can you add them? We can't reproduce this code.

Comment: sorry, my error is " 'int' object has no attribute 'array' "

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish, but your error is because built-in Python number types don't have an array attribute attached to them. Let's look at an example:

```
distancia = int(partes[2])
```

To make an analogy:

```
distance = int("7")
print(distance)  # 7
print(type(distance))  # <type 'int'>
```

Now let's look at all the methods provided for **int** type primitives:

```
print(dir(distance))  #  ['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__class__', '__cmp__', 
# '__coerce__', '__delattr__', '__div__', '__divmod__', '__doc__', '__float__', 
#'__floordiv__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getnewargs__', '__hash__', 
# '__hex__', #'__index__', '__init__', '__int__', '__invert__', '__long__', '__lshift__', 
# '__mod__', #'__mul__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__oct__', '__or__', 
# '__pos__', '__pow__', #'__radd__', '__rand__', '__rdiv__', '__rdivmod__', '__reduce__', 
# '__reduce_ex__', #'__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rlshift__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', 
# '__ror__', '__rpow__', , 'conjugate', 'denominator', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real',
#'__rrshift__', '__rshift__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', 
#'__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '__trunc__', 
#'__xor__', 'bit_length']`
```

As you can see, **array** is not a method that exists for built-in **int** types, so you're
going to have to rethink of a way to achieve the functionality you are after.